# Simply transitive action and $G$-isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, orbit-stabilizer

$\newcommand{\stab}{\text{Stab}}$
$\newcommand{\orb}{\text{Orb}}$
Situating definitions.

> **Definition:** Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$, we say the action is *simply transitive* if it is transitive and $\stab(x)$ is trivial for all $x \in X$.
>
> **Definition:** Let $G$ act on two sets $X,Y$. We say that $X$ is $G$-isomorphic to $Y$ if there exists a bijection $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $f(g \ast x) = g \ast f(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and $g \in G$.

**Problem:** Show that if the action of $G$ on $X$ is simply transitive, then it is $G$-isomorphic to $G$ with the left-multiplication action $g \ast h = gh$.

*Attempt:* Let $x \in X$, then the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem gives a bijection $f:G/\stab(x) \rightarrow \orb(x)$ by $f(g\stab(x)) = g \ast x$. Because the action of $G$ on $X$ is simply transitive we have that $\orb(x) = X$ for all $x \in X$ and that $\stab(x) = \{1_G\}$ for all $x \in X$. This means the bijection is really from $f:G/\{1\} \rightarrow X$. But $\{1\} \unlhd G$ and so $G/\{1\}$ is a quotient group which is evidently isomorphic to $G$. Therefore we have a bijection $f:G \rightarrow X$; to see that it is a $G$-isomorphism, let $g \in G$, $x \in X$ and $a \in X$
\begin{align*}
f(g \ast a) & = f(ga) \\
& = (ga)\ast x \\
&= g \ast (a \ast x)\\
& = g \ast f(a).
\end{align*}

What Im not quite sure about is keeping the same bijection when we use that $G/\{1\} \cong G$. I know that you can certainly compose the isomorphism map $\psi:G/\{1\} \rightarrow G$ so that we have a bijection $f': \psi \circ f$ but will that change how the map $f$ is defined? Because I guess I'm making the assumption that even when $f$ doesn't map from a set of cosets it acts as $g \mapsto g \ast x$ rather than $g\stab(x) \mapsto g \ast x$. Are there any hints/tips for how to clean this up?

Comment: (For $x\in X$ fixed) define $f:G\to X$ more directly by $f(g)=g\ast x$, and prove it is bijective (using the hypothesis of simple transitivity).

Comment: I think I get that fixing $x \in X$ we have that because the action is transitive, there is $g \in G$ for which $g \ast x = x$ and so $f(g) = x$ for any $x$ and the action is surjective. For injectivity I know I want to show that $ g_1 \ast x = g_2 \ast x$ implies $g_1=g_2$ but I can't seem to see why it follows from simple transitivity. Any hints that don't immediately give it @AnneBauval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For $x∈X$ fixed) define $f:G→X$ more directly by $f(g)=g∗x$.

$f$ is onto because (since the action is transitive) for any $y\in X$ there exists a $g\in G$ such that $y=g∗x$.

$f$ is one-to-one because for any $g,h\in G$ such that $f(g)=f(h)$, $g^{-1}h$ fixes $x$ hence (since this transitivity is "simple") $g^{-1}h=e_G$, so $g=h.$

Comment: I don't know if I follow why the step is legal. Because as far as I understand we're concluding from $f(g) = f(h)$ means that $g_1 \ast x = g_2 \ast x$, and then $g_2^{-1} g_1 \ast x = x$? But why can we do what naively seems like left multiplication to me? Why is this a legal operation? Aren't the group actions technically maps? Sorry I'm sure it's basic.

Comment: A group action satisfies (by definition) $e_G*x=x$ and $g*(h*y)=(gh)*y.$ Here, if $g_1*x=g_2*x$ then$$(g_2^{-1}g_1)*x=g_2^{-1}*(g_1*x)=g_2^{-1}*(g_2*x)=(g_2^{-1}g_2)*x=e_G*x=x.$$

Comment: Oh so this isn't actually left multiplication? Just this process in the background?

Comment: The map $G\times G\to G$ is the multiplication (the group operation), the map $G\times X\to X$ is a group action, which (by definition) has to satisfy these two compatibility rules.

Comment: The fact that all stabilizers are trivial is actually much stronger than being faithful (ie the kernel of the action is the identity), it means the action is free. Cheers!

Comment: @Bcpicao Thanks, I removed my mistaken and useless words.